# Vega: compute tooltip key from a signal

Tags: tooltip, vega

Apparently, tooltip object accepts (computes) signals in the values, but not the objects, and does not work well with `{[signal]: value}` notation.

Is there any alternative way to set the tooltip keys dynamically, based on the vega signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now “hacked” it through custom sanitize function for the vegaTooltip:

```
function mySanitize(value){
    return String(value).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace('METRIC', VIEW.signal('metric'))
};
```